# Hide _id from a nested document after a lookup operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to hide the _id value from a nested document but I am not able to achieve the proper syntax. I am always getting errors no matter how I try.

My actual code:

```
db.integration.aggregate([
{
  $match: {"integration_name" : "a-to-b" }
},
{
    $lookup: 
        {
            from: "service",
            localField: "from",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "from"
        }
},
{
    $lookup: 
        {
            from: "service",
            localField: "to",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "to"
        }
},
{
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      integration_name: true,
      from: { $arrayElemAt: ["$from",0]},
      to: { $arrayElemAt: ["$to",0]},
      inbound_settings: true,
      outbound_settings: true
    }
}])
```

Actual output:

```
{ 
"integration_name" : "a-to-b", 
"inbound_settings" : {
    "pattern_matching" : "*.xml", 
    "polling_frequency" : 1000.0, 
    "backup_directory" : "/backup"
}, 
"outbound_settings" : {
    "pattern_matching" : "*.xml", 
    "polling_frequency" : 1000.0, 
    "backup_directory" : "/backup"
}, 
"from" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9821f02c669a3c40bd2a63"), 
    "name" : "a", 
    "connection_details" : {
        "protocol" : "ftp", 
        "host" : "localhost", 
        "port" : 21.0, 
        "path" : "/Users/rabobank/files/", 
        "user" : "rabobank", 
        "password" : "rabobank"
    }
}, 
"to" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9821e32c669a3c40bd2a62"), 
    "name" : "b", 
    "connection_details" : {
        "protocol" : "ftp", 
        "host" : "localhost", 
        "port" : 22.0, 
        "path" : "/Users/deutschebank/files/", 
        "user" : "deutschebank", 
        "password" : "deutschebank"
    }
}}
```

Both "from" and "to" fields are nested document. What I am trying to achieve is to hide the from._id and to._id values.

Expected Output:

```
{ 
"integration_name" : "a-to-b", 
"inbound_settings" : {
    "pattern_matching" : "*.xml", 
    "polling_frequency" : 1000.0, 
    "backup_directory" : "/backup"
}, 
"outbound_settings" : {
    "pattern_matching" : "*.xml", 
    "polling_frequency" : 1000.0, 
    "backup_directory" : "/backup"
}, 
"from" : {
    "name" : "a", 
    "connection_details" : {
        "protocol" : "ftp", 
        "host" : "localhost", 
        "port" : 21.0, 
        "path" : "/Users/rabobank/files/", 
        "user" : "rabobank", 
        "password" : "rabobank"
    }
}, 
"to" : {
    "name" : "b", 
    "connection_details" : {
        "protocol" : "ftp", 
        "host" : "localhost", 
        "port" : 22.0, 
        "path" : "/Users/deutschebank/files/", 
        "user" : "deutschebank", 
        "password" : "deutschebank"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more projection stage:

```
{
    $project: {
      "from._id": false,
      "to._id": false
    }
}
```

Comment: this breaks aggregation `{ MongoError: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion`

Comment: @Kunok, it's been fixed somewhere in 2.4 or 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `_id: 0` while `$project` in your case query should be like below, And you can also set `FromId: '$from._id', ToId: '$to._id'`

```
 {
  $project: {
   'to._id': 0,
   'from._id': 0,
   'FromId': '$from._id', //It's optional
   'ToId': '$to._id' //It's optional

 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "class._id": 0,
      "master._id":0,
      "course._id":0
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**